# How do I get a search box to appear alongside my site listing in Google search results a-la Wikipedia

Tags: search

[alt text http://blog.chomperstomp.com/img/wikipediaGoogle.png](http://blog.chomperstomp.com/img/wikipediaGoogle.png)

How can I get a search box like this listed for my website?

Comment: I don't think you have control of this option. It depends on Google

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to customize google search result of my website](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5433431/how-to-customize-google-search-result-of-my-website)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

http://googleblog.blogspot.com/2008/03/search-within-site-tale-of.html

> This feature will now occur when we detect a high probability that a user wants more refined search results within a specific site.

Essentially, you can't. This is only likely to occur on high-traffic sites with usage cases that lend themselves to this sort of search-within-search.

Comment: It looks like when Google detects that a large percentage of your visitors go straight for the search box when they hit your homepage, you get the search box in your listing.

Answer (score 3):

You can't choose what todo with these links it's under Google controls, more info [here](http://googlewebmastercentral.blogspot.com/2009/09/using-named-anchors-to-identify.html)