# How to customize google search result of my website

Tags: seo, google-search

i want to customize the google result for my website as when i search for the dictionary.com or microsoft.com
then in the result page it show the some links and a text box below.

I want to customize the google result for my website and want to display links and a text box below the result.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Links below site in google search](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2098602/links-below-site-in-google-search)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The 8 links that appear below the main search result are called **sitelinks**. You cannot control whether they appear or not - this is controlled by Google. The same for the search box - only Google can decide if/when it appears.

Read up on sitelinks here:
http://www.google.com/support/webmasters/bin/answer.py?answer=47334

The most important factor for sitelinks is that you must be the ***clear first search result*** for the searched keyword.

There are a number of other things you can do to make yourself attractive to Google so that sitelinks may appear:

- http://googlewebmastercentral.blogspot.com/2008/10/importance-of-link-architecture.html
- http://www.hochmanconsultants.com/articles/sitelinks.shtml

Good luck.

Answer (score 1):

Google provides some information on providing sitemaps [here](http://www.google.com/support/webmasters/bin/answer.py?hl=en&answer=156184&from=40318&rd=1) which will help your site become more easily indexed by search engines. Numerous automated tools exist to create sitemaps for you. Unfortunately there is no way to request automated links to pages of your site like you're describing; Google generates this content themselves and does not offer any control over it. Your goal should be to make a very SEO-friendly site and over time perhaps Google will begin providing this for you.